# Quarkus Rest service Heap memory is growing without any request

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a Quarkus REST  API, Which used hibernate Panache to connect to Database. Installed feature while running application is

`Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, security, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui]`

There is no request I have placed so far, but my heap memory is getting increased to 500mb in 30 minutes. Is it normal? After sometime GC executed and memory became free. Again heap started growing.

Comment: It can be normal, depending on your application size, initialization and gc configuration, can you provide a reproducer?

Comment: It sounds very normal to me. Provided that the memory is released after GC, I wouldn't worry about it. You can log garbage collections to get more detail, see https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/MemoryManagement for native images.